# Cross tab pivot table using Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

is there any ability to create pivot table in microsoft excel like below:

Source data:

`Id     Gender  VisitAttr   VisitAttrValue  PersonDetails      Person  Value
220225  M      VisitStatus     OPD             Religion            Hindu
220224  M      VisitStatus     OPD             Religion            Christian
220225  M      VisitStatus     OPD             class               OBC
220225  M      VisitStatus     OPD             Occupation          farmer`

Expected format:

`Id  Gender VisitStatus Religion Class Occupation
 22025  M   OPD          Hindu     OBC   farmer
 22024  M   OPD          Christian`

I tried to achieve above using Pivot table function in Excel. But it excepts some grouping function to be achieved for data values. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not from the data layout as shown. Your data would have to be normalised first (which I assume you can manage) and in any case VALUES will only output numeric values (or blanks/zeros).